# Creating a libs folder in maven

Tags: maven-2, installation

First of all I should state that I understand that typically with Maven this is not how you should do things...

What I am looking for is how you would deploy maven artifacts to a repository existing in the lib folder of your project.  I know how to add a repository on my local filesystem to pom.xml like this...

```
 <repositories>
            <repository>
                    <id>lib-repo</id>
                    <name>lib-repository</name>
                    <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>                
                    <releases>
                            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
                    </releases>
            </repository>
    </repositories>
```

The confusing part is how I would get artifacts in to this "lib" folder.  It's not as simply as dropping in files, I have the feeling I need to use the mvn install:install-file command somehow.

Comment: Do you mean deploy like deploy:deploy or install like install:install-file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I can use this (I answered my own question rather fast it seems!).

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `deploy` or `install`? In maven's vocabulary, *deploying* is adding your artifact(s) to a remote repository and typically occurs during the `deploy` phase. This is done using the [depoy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) that has two goals: [deploy:deploy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) and [deploy:deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html).

To use the plugin, declare where to deploy to the `pom.xml` by adding a [`repository`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-model/maven.html#class_repository) element under the `distributionManagement` element:

```
<project>
  ...
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>projectRepository</id>
      <name>Repository Name</name>
      <url>Wagon Url</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
  ...
</project>
```

About the `repository`:

- The `id` is a unique id for this repository (so you can refer to it in `~/.m2/settings.xml` for authentication settings).
- The `name` is a human-readable name for the repository.
- The `url` is a [Wagon](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/) URL, most often `scp`.

As you can see in Wagon's documentation, wagon has a [File](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-file/) provider too. It enables Maven to use remote repositories stored in local file system and to store Maven sites there also. In other words, you can use `file://C:\m2-repo` or `file://${basedir}/lib` as `url`.